# Can't connect to MongoDB docker from Compass

Tags: mongodb, docker

I created a MongoDB docker instance as follows:

```
sudo docker run --name mongo -d -p 27000:27000  mongo
```

I confirmed that the instance is running by using command `sudo docker ps --all` :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                      NAMES
f509276287eb   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:27000->27000/tcp, :::27000->27000/tcp, 27017/tcp   mongo
```

Then I tried to connect to it using Compass GUI tool with the following connection string:

```
mongodb://localhost:27000/
```

I get a screen the following screen:

[image: waiting for connection]

and after waiting for a while, the screen disappears with the following error message

```
connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:27000 closed
```

My goal is to use this docker image to run tests, but I cannot connect to it.

I tried using `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` but it didn't work.

**My Question:** How do I connect to MongoDB docker image?

---

Environment info:

- OS is Ubuntu 22.04
- Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086349 (snap package)
- Compass version 1.33.1 (deb package)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I made a silly mistake when picking the port, I should have used:

```
sudo docker run --name mongo -d -p 27000:27017  mongo
```

Because Mongo will always be on port `27017` inside the image.

Comment: With `mongod`, you could also specify a different port to use instead of the default `27017`. See also [mongod: Specify a TCP port](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#specify-a-tcp-port)

Comment: I did not know that. thansk for the tip @WanBachtiar